# Shift Verbatim environment to the left using \hspace

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, fancyvrb

I pasted some code into a document in a `Verbatim` environment from `fancyvrb`. Because it is within two nested `enumerate` environments, the code is indented quite far over. As a result, one long line of code extends off the page. The quickest fix that I could think of was to place a `\hspace` command with a negative argument just before the `Verbatim` environment in order to shift the whole `Verbatim` environment over to the left a few cm. However, this had no effect. Can someone suggest a solution please? See MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{fancyvrb}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \begin{enumerate}
   \item First sub-item

   \hspace{-5cm}\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\tiny]
    This line of code is nice and short and fits nicely on the page.
    This line of code is very long and does not fit onto the page!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!The End
   \end{Verbatim}
  \end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Verbatim is a list and uses as leftmargin `\@totalleftmargin`. So you can change this locally:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{fancyvrb}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \begin{enumerate}
   \item First sub-item

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@totalleftmargin=-1cm
   \begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\tiny]
    This line of code is nice and short and fits nicely on the page.
    This line of code is very long and does not fit onto the page!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!The End
   \end{Verbatim}
\endgroup

  \end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution with the `verbatimbox` package.  Note that this first solution will not break the verbatim across page boundaries.

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{verbatimbox}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \begin{enumerate}
   \item First sub-item

   \hspace{-5cm}\begin{verbbox}[\tiny]
    This line of code is nice and short and fits nicely on the page.
    This line of code is very long and does not fit onto the page!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!The End
   \end{verbbox}
   \theverbbox
  \end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For a solution that can break the verbatim across page boundaries, with the `\hspace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{verbatimbox}
\textheight 1.5in
 \begin{document}
 \begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \begin{enumerate}
   \item First sub-item

   \begin{verbnobox}[\tiny\hspace{-4cm}]
    This line of code is nice and short and fits nicely on the page.
    This line of code is very long and does not fit onto the page!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!The End
    This line of code is nice and short and fits nicely on the page.
    This line of code is very long and does not fit onto the page!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!The End
    This line of code is nice and short and fits nicely on the page.
    This line of code is very long and does not fit onto the page!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!The End
    This line of code is nice and short and fits nicely on the page.
    This line of code is very long and does not fit onto the page!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!The End
    This line of code is nice and short and fits nicely on the page.
    This line of code is very long and does not fit onto the page!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!The End
    This line of code is nice and short and fits nicely on the page.
    This line of code is very long and does not fit onto the page!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!The End
    This line of code is nice and short and fits nicely on the page.
    This line of code is very long and does not fit onto the page!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!The End
    This line of code is nice and short and fits nicely on the page.
    This line of code is very long and does not fit onto the page!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!The End
   \end{verbnobox}
  \end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) provides `xleftmargin` and `xrightmargin` as key-value settings to adjust the left/right margins of the verbatim text:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First sub-item

    \begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\tiny,xleftmargin=-5cm]
      This line of code is nice and short and fits nicely on the page.
      This line of code is very long and does not fit onto the page!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!The End
    \end{Verbatim}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Note though that spaces associated with your code indentation is necessarily included when using `Verbatim`. As such, one would typically use no indentation inside those environments, however awkward it may seem:

```
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First sub-item

    \begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\tiny,xleftmargin=-5cm]
This line of code is nice and short and fits nicely on the page.
This line of code is very long and does not fit onto the page!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!The End
    \end{Verbatim}
  \end{enumerate}
```